# selectBoxIt with Datatable pagination not working

Tags: jquery, datatables, selectboxit

I have used [selectBoxIt](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgregfranko.com%2Fjquery.selectBoxIt.js%2F&ei=vpxIVahhk7i4BNiSgYgB&usg=AFQjCNESUEL-XGQzdj4hwCyVN2GgrcQRrw&bvm=bv.92291466,d.c2E) for selectbox to designing a dropdown box and used datatable for listing of data.

So, It is not working when paginate in datatable list.Code i have done for selectbox is

```
 var selectBox = $(".filter_group").selectBoxIt({ theme: "jqueryui", native: true });
```

But it is not working with pagination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pls  try with below code.

```
fnDrawCallback : function() {
  var selectBox = $(".filter_group").selectBoxIt({ theme: "jqueryui", native: true });
}
```